# Reason behind the definition of the representation of $Hom(V,W)$

Tags: representation-theory, tensor-products

Let $\rho: G \to GL(V)$ and $\sigma: G \to GL(W)$ be representations. The dual representation of $\rho$, namely $\rho ^* $, is defined as follows:
$\rho^*(g)=\ ^t\rho(g^{-1})$.

The reason for this definition is that we want the two representations
of $G$ with respect to the natural pairing between $V^* $ and $V$ satisfy the following condition: $$ \langle \rho ^* (g)(v^* ),\rho(g)(v) \rangle=\langle v^* ,v \rangle . \ \ \ \ \ (I)$$

The representation $\text{Hom}(V,W)$ is defined as follows: $$(g\phi)(v)=g(\phi(g^{-1}v))=\sigma_g(\phi(\rho_{g^{-1}}(v)));\ \ \ \phi \in \text{Hom}(V,W).$$

Now I want to see the reason behind this definition much the same way there is a reason for the definition of dual representations. Therefore, I did as follows.

$\text{Hom}(V,W) \cong V^* \otimes W $. I identify $ \phi \in \text{Hom}(V,W) $ as $\phi \otimes 1 \in V^* \otimes W$ and $(v^* \otimes w)(u)=v^* (u)w $. Hence, $$(g\phi)(v)=\left[ (\rho^* \otimes \sigma)_g(\phi \otimes 1)\right](v) =\rho_g^* (\phi)(v) \sigma_g(1)=$$ $$(\text{because of (I)})\ \phi(\rho_{g^-1}(v))\sigma_g(1)= $$ $$\sigma_g(\phi(\rho_{g^-1}(v)))=$$ $$(g\phi)(v).$$

Is this argument rigorous enough? or does it require more consideration?

Comment: Note that there Was a question about this before: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4301605/348926

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The representation $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$ is supposed to be the [internal hom](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+hom) of $V$ and $W$ in the category of linear representations of $G$ (and we kind of expect that the underlying vector space is the internal hom inside the category of vector space, i.e. the usual vector space of linear maps). This means that we want the adjunction map

$$\mathrm{Hom}_G(U,\mathrm{Hom}(V,W)) \to \mathrm{Hom}_G(U \otimes V,W),\quad \alpha \mapsto (u \otimes v) \mapsto \alpha(u)(v)$$

to be a bijection, where $G$ acts on $U \otimes V$ via $g \cdot (u \otimes v) := (g \cdot u) \otimes (g \cdot v)$. In particular, it needs to be well-defined. So for a $G$-map $\alpha : U \to \mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$ the map $(u \otimes v) \mapsto \alpha(u)(v)$ needs to be a $G$-map, i.e. $\alpha(g \cdot u)(g \cdot v) = g \cdot \alpha(u)(v)$. Since $\alpha$ is a $G$-map, this means $(g \cdot \alpha(u))(g \cdot v) = g \cdot \alpha(u)(v)$. Letting $\beta = \alpha(u)$ and $v' = g \cdot v$, we find
$$(g \cdot \beta)(v') = g \cdot \beta(g^{-1} \cdot v').$$
This motivates the definition of the $G$-action on $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$.

The same method also works for $G$-sets (and in fact, $G$-objects in arbitrary monoidal closed categories). The approach $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W) \cong V^* \otimes W$ only works for finite-dimensional vector spaces and does not really show what is going on, in my opinion.

Even more generally, let $\mathcal{C}$ be any symmetric monoidal closed category and $H \in \mathcal{C}$ be a [Hopf algebra object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hopf+monoid) in $\mathcal{C}$. Then the category $\mathbf{Mod}_H$ of left $H$-modules inherits a symmetric closed monoidal structure. In "element notation", the action on $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$ is $(a \cdot f)(v) = a \cdot f(s(a) \cdot v
)$ where $s : H \to H$ is the antipode. (I haven't checked the details.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more simple-minded motivation for the definition of the $G$-action on linear maps $\phi:V\to W$. Think of a function like $\phi$ as "officially" a set of ordered pairs (its graph); if $\phi(v)=w$, then $\langle v,w\rangle\in\phi$. Now, to apply some $g\in G$ to $\phi$, just apply it to both components of all the ordered pairs in $\phi$. In other words, if $\langle v,w\rangle\in\phi$, then $\langle g(v),g(w)\rangle\in g(\phi)$. In yet other words, if $\phi(v)=w$ then $g(\phi)(g(v))=g(w)$. Apply this with $v$ replaced by $g^{-1}(v)$ to get the definition of $g(\phi)$ that you quoted.

Answer (score 1):

Although I think Martin's answer motivating the action on $\text{Hom}(V,W)$ via the notion of an internal Hom-functor is a very nice point of view, I'm not sure it is fair to say that the OP's approach only works in the finite-dimensional case:

Composition gives a natural linear map $c\colon \text{Hom}(V,U)\otimes \text{Hom}(U,W) \to \text{Hom}(V,W)$.

1. Taking $V=W=\mathsf k$ (where $\mathsf k$ is the field we are working over) gives the natural pairing $e\colon U\otimes U^* \to \mathsf k$, where if $v\in U$, $f\in U^*$ then $e(v\otimes f)= f(e)$.  If the $G$-action is to be compatible with composition (which is necessary from the point of view of internal homs), then
   $$
   f(v)= g(e(v,f)) = e(g(v),g(f)) = g(f)(g(v))
   $$
   and letting $v' = g(v)$ this yields $g(f)(v') = f(g^{-1}(v')$ for all $v'\in U$, and we recover the definition of the action on $U^*$.
2. Next, taking $U=\mathsf k$ composition yields a natural map $c\colon V^*\otimes W \to \text{Hom}(V,W)$ (since $\text{Hom}(\mathsf k,W) \cong W$ via the canonical map $\psi\mapsto \psi(1)$). Then $c$ is injective, and its image is the span of the space of rank $1$ linear maps (since the image of a pure tensor is a composition $V\to \mathsf k \to W$), that is, the finite rank linear maps from $V$ to $W$.

If the action of $G$ on $\text{Hom}$-spaces is such that it is compatible with composition (which it must from the point of view of internal Homs) then $c$ must be a homomorphism of $G$-representations, and hence it follows $g(\phi)= g\phi g^{-1}$ for any $\phi\colon V\to W$ of finite rank. Since it is then trivial to check that this action extends to an action on all of $\text{Hom}(V,W)$, we are naturally led to the definition of the $G$-action on the full Hom space.

Alternatively, if $\mathcal V$ denotes the category of finite-dimensional subspaces of $V$, with morphisms given by inclusion maps, then $V= \text{colim}_{V_1\in\mathcal V} V_1$ so that

$$
\text{Hom}(V,W) = \text{Hom}(\text{colim}_{V_1\in \mathcal V} V_1,W) = \text{lim}_{V_1 \in \mathcal V} \text{Hom}(V_1,W) = \text{lim}_{V_1 \in \mathcal V}(V_1^*\otimes W)
$$
thus if $V$ is locally finite, that is, if $V$ is the sum of its finite-dimensional subrepresentations (which is always the case, say for representations of algebraic groups), then any $G$-action on $\text{Hom}(V,W)$ which is compatible with composition is determined by that on $\text{Hom}(V_1,W)$ for $V_1$ finite-dimensional and hence has to be $g\cdot\phi = g\phi g^{-1}$

Comment: Absolutely, what I wanted to point out was that even if $\dim(V)= \infty$ you still have an embedding of $V^*\otimes W$ into Hom(V,W) which tells you something (admittedly not if V has no finite dimensional subreps!)

Answer (score 1):

There is also another motivation that seems worth mentioning.

If $V$ and $W$ are $\mathsf k$-vector spaces, then composition of linear maps makes $\text{Hom}(V,W)$ into a $\text{End}(V)\otimes \text{End}(W)^{\text{op}}$-bimodule, and hence a representation of $\text{GL}(V)\times \text{GL}(W)^{\text{op}}$.

Now if $G_1,G_2$ are groups, and $\text{mor}(G_1,G_2)$ denotes the set of group homomorphism from $G_1$ to $G_2$, then $\phi\in \text{mor}(G_1,G_2)$ if and only if $\phi(g_1g_2)=\phi(g_1)\phi(g_2)$ for all $g_1,g_2\in G_1$. But then since, for $g_1,g_2 \in G_1$, the product of $g_1$ and $g_2$ in $G_1^{\text{op}}$ is $g_2g_1$, $\phi \in \text{mor}(G_1^{\text{op}},G_2^{\text{op}})$ if and only if $\phi(g_2g_1) = \phi(g_2)\phi(g_1)$ for all $g_1,g_2 \in G_1$, and thus $\text{mor}(G_1,G_2) = \text{mor}(G_1^{\text{op}},G_2^{\text{op}})$.

Now if $V$ and $W$ are also representations of a group $G$ then we have homomorphism $\rho\colon G\to \text{GL}(V)$ and $\sigma\colon G\to \text{GL}(W)$, and so using the previous paragraph we see that
$$
\rho\times\sigma \colon G\times G^{\text{op}} \to \text{GL}(V)\times \text{GL}(W)^{\text{op}}
$$
is a homomorphism of groups, and hence $\text{Hom}(V,W)$ is naturally a $G\times G^{\text{op}}$-representation. Since the diagonal map $\Delta\colon G\to G\times G$ where $\Delta(g)= (g,g)$ is a homomorphism, we are thus reduced to finding either a homomorphism $i_G$ from $G$ to its opposite or a homomorphism $i_W$ from $\text{GL}(W)$ to its opposite (since then $(\rho\times \sigma)\circ (1\times i_G)\circ \Delta$ or $(1\times i_W)\circ(\rho\times \sigma)\circ \Delta$ will give the required homomorphism).

In fact, for any group $G$, the inversion map $\iota_G\colon G\to G$ gives a canonical homomorphism from $G$ to its opposite, hence using either $\iota_G$ or $\iota_{\text{GL}(W)}$ we obtain a homomorphism from $G$ to $\text{GL}(V)\times \text{GL}(W)^{\text{op}}$. Moreover, since for any homormorphism of groups $\phi\colon G_1\to G_2$ we have $\phi(g)^{-1} = \phi(g^{-1})$, they both yield the same action.

Finally, it is perhaps worth saying that since the $G$-action on $V^* = \text{Hom}(V,\mathsf k)$ is a special case of the action of $G$ on $\text{Hom}$-spaces, there is some advantage to being able to find an action on $\text{Hom}$ spaces without already knowing an action on dual spaces.